# Preferred method to daemonize vagrant plugin

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-plugin

Is there a preferred method to daemonize a [vagrant plugin](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/plugins/)?

I am using [vagrant-fsnotify](https://github.com/adrienkohlbecker/vagrant-fsnotify) which runs a process on the host to send file change events from the host to the guest.

Comment: did you come up with a solution for this?

Comment: See the accepted solution @Martinffx -- which is what we ended up doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant plugins have access to [Vagrant "Action Hooks"](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/plugins/action-hooks.html) which are useful for extending expected events.

For example, I could extend the fsnotify functionality to use Daemons for background-processing capabilities. Then, tie into the Vagrant Action Hook [up](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/plugins/action-hooks.html#machine_action_up) and [halt](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/plugins/action-hooks.html#machine_action_halt) to trigger the start of fsnotify, and trigger the stop of fsnotify.

[Here is a good example vagrant-plugin](https://github.com/monochromegane/vagrant-uptime/blob/master/lib/vagrant-uptime/action/up.rb) that uses action-hooks.

Answer (score 0):

One potential would be to write a zsh/bash wrapper script to start the process on startup (if it's not already started) and stop it on machine death.

This would require the [Daemons](https://github.com/thuehlinger/daemons) wrapper to daemonizie the process away from a shell

Answer (score 0):

The Vagrantfile gets run every time the `vagrant` command is called. So you could throw specific ruby code in there, though that seems an anti-pattern.